# look up a value in a dictionary string comparison for date time stamp

Tags: python

If I have data like this where the time block is on 15 minute intervals:

```
dict_df = [{'Time Block': '2021-08-19 00:00:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 00:15:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 00:30:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 00:45:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 01:00:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 01:15:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 01:30:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 01:45:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 02:00:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 02:15:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 02:30:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 02:45:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 03:00:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 03:15:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 03:30:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 03:45:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 04:00:00', 'charmany': 1},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 04:15:00', 'charmany': 1},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 04:30:00', 'charmany': 1},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 04:45:00', 'charmany': 1},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 05:00:00', 'charmany': 1},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 05:15:00', 'charmany': 1},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 05:30:00', 'charmany': 1},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 05:45:00', 'charmany': 1},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 06:00:00', 'charmany': 1},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 06:15:00', 'charmany': 1},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 06:30:00', 'charmany': 1},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 06:45:00', 'charmany': 1},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 07:00:00', 'charmany': 1},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 07:15:00', 'charmany': 1},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 07:30:00', 'charmany': 1},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 07:45:00', 'charmany': 1},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 08:00:00', 'charmany': 1},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 08:15:00', 'charmany': 1},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 08:30:00', 'charmany': 1},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 08:45:00', 'charmany': 1},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 09:00:00', 'charmany': 1},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 09:15:00', 'charmany': 1},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 09:30:00', 'charmany': 1},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 09:45:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 10:00:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 10:15:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 10:30:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 10:45:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 11:00:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 11:15:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 11:30:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 11:45:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 12:00:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 12:15:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 12:30:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 12:45:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 13:00:00', 'charmany': 2},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 13:15:00', 'charmany': 2},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 13:30:00', 'charmany': 2},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 13:45:00', 'charmany': 2},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 14:00:00', 'charmany': 2},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 14:15:00', 'charmany': 2},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 14:30:00', 'charmany': 2},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 14:45:00', 'charmany': 2},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 15:00:00', 'charmany': 2},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 15:15:00', 'charmany': 2},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 15:30:00', 'charmany': 2},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 15:45:00', 'charmany': 2},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 16:00:00', 'charmany': 2},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 16:15:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 16:30:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 16:45:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 17:00:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 17:15:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 17:30:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 17:45:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 18:00:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 18:15:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 18:30:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 18:45:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 19:00:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 19:15:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 19:30:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 19:45:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 20:00:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 20:15:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 20:30:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 20:45:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 21:00:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 21:15:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 21:30:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 21:45:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 22:00:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 22:15:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 22:30:00', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 22:45:01', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 23:00:01', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 23:15:01', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 23:30:01', 'charmany': 0},
         {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 23:45:01', 'charmany': 0}]
```

How would I lookup a payload value (called `charmany`) based on a time stamp value that is a string? For example how would I find this payload based on the time block string?

```
find_this_payload = '2021-08-19 07:49:00'
```

I would want to retrieve this int value of `1`:

```
     {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 07:45:00', 'charmany': 1}, <----
     {'Time Block': '2021-08-19 08:00:00', 'charmany': 1},
```

As the string value representing`Time Block` for `find_this_payload` is less than `08:00:00` but greater than `07:45:00`

trying to loop through the dictionary values inside the list `dict_df`:

```
for val in dict_df:
    for block,payload in val.items():
        print(payload)
```

I can print the time block strings and payload values but could use a tip on actually incorporating a look up function. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to search for values in between your key values, you're really looking for something like [`bisect.bisect_left`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left). Unfortunately `bisect_left` doesn't support custom compare functions so you'll have to write your own binary search. Fortunately that's not too difficult.

```py
import datetime

def find_charmanv(dict_df, timestamp):
    target_val = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(timestamp)
    lo, hi = 0, len(dict_df)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        mid_val = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(dict_df[mid]['Time Block'])
        if mid_val < target_val:
            lo = mid + 1
        elif mid_val > target_val:
            hi = mid
        else:
            break
    return dict_df[mid]['charmany']
```

```py
>>> find_charmanv(dict_df, '2021-08-19 09:30:10')
1
```

If you're going to search the same list many times, it would probably be worth restructuring your data to include the `datetime` representation directly in the list so you don't have to parse the same strings every time you search.

Comment: Any chance you could explain that more about "going to search the same list many time" which I think I will for sure. So I understand this correctly, I can probably just parse or modify the list directly `'Time Block': '2021-08-19 00:00:00'` for a datetime representation

Comment: I am still trying to wrap my head around how your answer works, thank you for posting.  I am still a newb with algorithms & data structures, would this be considered recursive approach?

Comment: @HenryHub 1) If you change the timestamp representation in your list from a string to a `datetime` before you searched then you wouldn't have to parse the strings as you search - this would be an optimization if you needed to search many many times; 2) This [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) implementation uses an iterative approach rather than recursive; 3) Any time format will work with some tweaking but your list needs to be sorted in time order

Answer (score 0):

Just compare the `Time Block` element with what you're searching for.

```
for val in dict_df:
    if val['Time Block'] == find_this_payload:
        print(val['charmony'])
        break # remove this if there can be multiple matches
```

Comment: On the `find_this_payload` the data can be sub 15 minute intervals. Thats the hard part is quite often `val['Time Block'] == find_this_payload` may not happen. Hopefully that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

If you can use pandas and datetime you can use

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

#dict_df code#

find_this_payload = datetime.fromisoformat('2021-08-19 07:49:00')

dict_df = pd.DataFrame(dict_df)

dict_df['Time Block'] = pd.to_datetime(dict_df['Time Block'])

dict_df.loc[lambda x: x['Time Block']<find_this_payload].tail(1)['charmany']
```